# OpenVPN resets connection repeadly

Tags: networking, openvpn, rdp

I have a OpenVPN server installed in an Amazon instance with Windows Server 2008 R2, and there's my client.

First i connect to my VPN
For some reason when i try to connect to my VPN server and RDP to it, the RDP's screen freezes after some seconds because the connection or tunnel is dropping after some seconds is established.

To set up tunnel first, i run this command:
sudo openvpn client.conf

The client.conf file has the following content:

```
#This is a client profile.
client
# We want to tunnel packets (rather than Ethernet bridging).
dev tun
# Use TCP instead of UDP.
proto tcp
# This is the VPN server we're connecting to.
# Be sure to change this value to YOUR Elastic IP address.
remote 107.23.174.205 443
# These are the crypto certificates we'll be using.
ca ca.crt
cert IanCert.crt
key IanCert.key
# Use LZO compression on the channel.
comp-lzo
#Verbosity
verb 3
```

After running that command, this is repeating in my terminal:

```
Mon Dec 31 03:35:03 2012 Connection reset, restarting [-1]
Mon Dec 31 03:35:03 2012 TCP/UDP: Closing socket
Mon Dec 31 03:35:03 2012 /sbin/route del -net 10.8.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.255
Mon Dec 31 03:35:03 2012 Closing TUN/TAP interface
Mon Dec 31 03:35:03 2012 /sbin/ifconfig tun0 0.0.0.0
Mon Dec 31 03:35:03 2012 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
Mon Dec 31 03:35:03 2012 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
Mon Dec 31 03:35:08 2012 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Mon Dec 31 03:35:08 2012 NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
Mon Dec 31 03:35:08 2012 WARNING: file 'IanCert.key' is group or others accessible
Mon Dec 31 03:35:08 2012 LZO compression initialized
Mon Dec 31 03:35:08 2012 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1544 D:140 EF:40 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Mon Dec 31 03:35:08 2012 Socket Buffers: R=[87380->131072] S=[16384->131072]
Mon Dec 31 03:35:08 2012 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1544 D:1450 EF:44 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Mon Dec 31 03:35:08 2012 Local Options hash (VER=V4): '69109d17'
Mon Dec 31 03:35:08 2012 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): 'c0103fa8'
Mon Dec 31 03:35:08 2012 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]107.23.174.205:443 [nonblock]
Mon Dec 31 03:35:09 2012 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]107.23.174.205:443
Mon Dec 31 03:35:09 2012 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
Mon Dec 31 03:35:09 2012 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]107.23.174.205:443
Mon Dec 31 03:35:09 2012 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]107.23.174.205:443, sid=79b44982 8fb01720
Mon Dec 31 03:35:11 2012 VERIFY OK: depth=1, /C=US/ST=VA/L=Haymarket/O=DKRDomain/OU=IT/CN=DKRDomain/name=Dave_Rensin/emailAddress=dave@dkrdomain.com
Mon Dec 31 03:35:11 2012 VERIFY OK: depth=0, /C=US/ST=VA/L=Haymarket/O=DKRDomain/OU=IT/CN=DKRDomain/name=Dave_Rensin/emailAddress=dave@dkrdomain.com
Mon Dec 31 03:35:14 2012 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Mon Dec 31 03:35:14 2012 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Mon Dec 31 03:35:14 2012 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Mon Dec 31 03:35:14 2012 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Mon Dec 31 03:35:14 2012 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 1024 bit RSA
Mon Dec 31 03:35:14 2012 [DKRDomain] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]107.23.174.205:443
Mon Dec 31 03:35:17 2012 SENT CONTROL [DKRDomain]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Mon Dec 31 03:35:17 2012 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,route 10.8.0.1,topology net30,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.8.0.6 10.8.0.5'
Mon Dec 31 03:35:17 2012 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Mon Dec 31 03:35:17 2012 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Mon Dec 31 03:35:17 2012 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Mon Dec 31 03:35:17 2012 ROUTE default_gateway=192.168.1.1
Mon Dec 31 03:35:17 2012 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Mon Dec 31 03:35:17 2012 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Mon Dec 31 03:35:17 2012 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Mon Dec 31 03:35:17 2012 /sbin/ifconfig tun0 10.8.0.6 pointopoint 10.8.0.5 mtu 1500
Mon Dec 31 03:35:17 2012 /sbin/route add -net 10.8.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 10.8.0.5
Mon Dec 31 03:35:17 2012 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

The only way to RDP to my instance (without setting up VPN) is by its public IP (but i don't want to it so, just for fixing this).
I'm using Mint Linux (or Debian 6) in my client.

Any ideas?